How can an (ideal) battery be connected in reverse?
So what happens if you connect, say a 9V ideal battery to a 3V ideal battery, but the negative end of one is connected to the negative end of the other? How would I find the current at which the 9V battery "charges" the 3V battery? I thought just use I = V/R but what do I put for R of a battery being connected in reverse?

Batteries can not charge normal batteries. the 9V batterie can get a current through the 3 V batterie and probably destroy it.

"So what happens if you connect, say a 9V ideal battery to a 3V ideal battery". They would  blow up. Even real batteries with internal resistance may get damaged, depending on their types.

Are you shorting the circuit? That is, do you also connect the positive ends of the batteries? If you put the arrangement in some larger circuit, then the combination acts as a 6V battery.

An ideal battery has zero internal resistance. Connecting one across the other is a straight short circuit.

The system is described by the equations $V=9$ and $V=3$. This is an inconsistent system of equations. There is no solution. The approximation of these batteries as ideal cannot hold. At least one must deviate substantially from ideal behavior.

The chemical reaction that generates the voltage in a primary (non-rechargeable) battery is not reversible. So attaching a battery in reverse to another battery ie. 9V + -3 is the equivalent of attaching a 9V battery to a resistor. If the ratio of the 9V battery voltage to the resistance of the battery in the reverse configuration is large enough ($Heat = \frac{V^2t}{R}$) then heat can be generated that damages the electrodes and electrolyte paste making the battery unusable. The internal resistance of the battery listed by the manufacturer should work as a value for R.

If you push idealized things to their limits, you sometimes calculate nonsense. You sometimes find out how they are different from ideal.
A real battery is something like an ideal battery with a small resistor inside. Usually you connect it to a circuit with a much bigger resistor. Ignoring the internal resistance is a good approximation to a real circuit.
If you short the terminals of an ideal battery together, you get $I = V/R$ where $r=0$. You can say that you can't solve this equation or the current is infinite.
A car battery is a pretty good approximation of an ideal battery. It has a low internal resistance, and can produce a large current. If you short it with a screwdriver, you can get enough current to turn the screwdriver red hot. It can ruin the battery, and ruin you to if the battery acid boils and ruptures the case.
A flashlight battery is less ideal. It has a higher internal resistance, so it cannot produce as large a current.
If you connect two batteries in series like that, the $9$ V battery will try to force current the wrong way through the $3$ V battery. What happens depends on the battery chemistry. Some batteries are designed to be recharged. Their internal chemistry runs backwards. They convert electrical energy back to chemical energy. Others are not designed this way. Either way, it isn't good for a real battery to run backwards with a large reverse voltage.
